# FIFO sequence on many queues for consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I have follow scheme:

[image]

Messages come in order of creation in specify queue. But consumer gets them depending on what queue he joined at first:

[image]

But I want to save order regardless of the queue:

[image]

Does RabbitMQ allows it?

Comment: Do you actually need multiple queues considering you seem to want ordered processing?

Comment: @Olivier, yes, i need multiple queues becuase different consumers connect to different queues.